# When I execute a cpio command, it hangs forever

Tags: freeze, cpio

I've been trying to unarchive a cpio archive (in this case, my initial ramdisk). However, when I try to extract the files, `cpio` hangs forever. It happens if I pass the `-V` argument to print extra info, too.

```
alex@alexs-arch-imac:/tmp/initramfs$ cpio -i initramfs-linux.img # wait for a while after this
^C
alex@alexs-arch-imac:/tmp/initramfs$
```

How can I extract a cpio archive without the utility hanging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some weird reason, `cpio` doesn't like to take a file argument. Instead, you have to pipe the archive into `cpio`. An inexperienced user would do the following:

```
cat initramfs-linux.img | cpio -i
```

However, this would get you the [Useless Use of cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). A better way would be:

```
cpio -i < initramfs-linux.img
```

This uses the shell's built-in redirection capabilities instead of spawning a new process.

Comment: The arguments specify the files to extract